# Onchange ,Arrow key up,down works in FF & Chrome but not work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

It is my jquery code

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 $(document).ready(function() {   
         $("#tasks").hide();
            $("select#categories").change(function(){
                    $("#tasks").show();
                    $.getJSON("ajax.php?module=responsibles&action=list_tasks",{id: $(this).val()}, function(j){

                            if($("#categories").val()=="-0") 
                            {                               
                                    $("#tasks").hide();
                            }
                            //if the div is hidden
                            $("div#form_objectifs").hide();
                            var options = '';
                            for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++)
                            {
                                    options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
                            }
                            $("#tasks").html(options);
                            $('#tasks option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');
                    })
            })  

 });
</script>
```

This code works fine on FF or Chrome,But not work in IE for Arrow Key UP,DOWN

Anybody

Comment: If you post more than 1 line of code and say "not work", you're [doing it wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem : 
there is no `keyup` or `keydown` event in your script. You use `change` event which be fired when your element loose focus.

Second problem :
You use `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` and in this you use `$(function(){ ... });`. It's two different way to write the same thing (the second is an alias of the first).
Choose one of them but not the both.

Third problem :
Please, best explain your problem so we can help you ;).